# A better method to check if an element exists than a `setTimeout` and `.length`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a function that clicks an element once it's dynamically generated, the problem is that I'm using something like this:

```
if($('#element').length){
  $('#element').click();
} else {
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#element').click();
  }, 500);
}
```

I keep calling this function until the element appears.
Is there a better way to keep checking if an element appeared ?
I tried using a loop, but I only ended up crashing the browser with an infinite loop

Comment: Trigger off the code that makes the element appear instead. (Can you post that code?)

Comment: It's the images from facebook's messenger, I'm making and jquery script that downloads them automatically (needed for work, nothing weird) some take longer than other to load that's why I need to keep checking until traveling the DOM to the next one

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Mutation Observer API to check when an element has been added.

```
var callback = function(mutations) {
// check the mutations and perform whatever you wish to do
}
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
// provide the node that you wish to observe for mutations and the configuration to use
observer.observe(<targetNode>, <config>);
...
...
observer.disconnect();
```

**Edit**: Added fiddle as an example where each dynamically added paragraph is echoed as an alert when it's added to the DOM.

[jsFiddle - echo dynamically added paragraphs with Mutation Observer API](https://jsfiddle.net/w10z8mtv/30)

Comment: That is going into the right direction, but you should improve the example so that it fits to the Ops usecase

Comment: @JonasW. Updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `.load()` event which is called when the element and all sub-elements have been completely loaded.

```
$( "#element" ).load(function() {
  // is completely loaded
});
```

Check [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) more.

> Note: This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images,
>   scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

If the element is not associated with any above, then it should be loaded on dom `.ready()` [event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).